Redirecting in the authorized callback?
I am following this tutorial on Nextjs.org: It uses Response.redirect inside the authorized callback:
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
 
export const authConfig = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/login',
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ auth, request: { nextUrl } }) {
      const isLoggedIn = !!auth?.user;
      const isOnDashboard = nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard');
      if (isOnDashboard) {
        if (isLoggedIn) return true;
        return false; // Redirect unauthenticated users to login page
      } else if (isLoggedIn) {
        return Response.redirect(new URL('/dashboard', nextUrl));
      }
      return true;
    },
  },
  providers: [], // Add providers with an empty array for now
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;

However, ChatGPT and Gemini both recommend not using redirect inside the authorized callback - it should only be used to determine whether the user is authorized to access that page/route.
But, given that this is the official tutorial - is this a valid pattern or not?

This code is written inside /auth.config.ts file as the tutorial says. and then this file is later imported inside /middleware.ts. So that means this Response.redirect() from callback is being called inside the middleware.
As nextjs API doc says about middleware is that:

Middleware executes before routes are rendered. It's particularly useful for implementing custom server-side logic like authentication, logging, or handling redirects.

So I think It might be a good place to write redirects.
But I don't exactly know in what aspect they (ChatGPT and Gemini) are not recommending using redirects in callbacks.
